# Failed to use a slider to control the rotate of svg pattern

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-pattern

I want to use a slider to control the rotation of `SVG` pattern by using `.setAttribute('patternTransform','rotate(slider.value)')` but it indicate an `error:"patterntranfom:expected numbers"`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAN96.png)

I will be very appreciated if someone has an idea about this problem,

you can check my code here

https://plnkr.co/edit/uiUoJBQuCOAtKtWy

```
var slider2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("slider2").value);
document.getElementById("pattern").setAttribute("patternTransform", "rotate(slider2)")
```

it is based on Rouby‘s previous answer

Comment: slider2 is not a number. You'd need to write \`rotate(${slider2})\` (Note the backticks rather than double quotes).

Comment: Try concat slider2 like `"rotate( " + slider2 + ")"`